# Using a TKinter entry box to search and bring up a frame

Tags: python, tkinter

Ive edited the code like Oakley said but it still errors. it errors out when i put in either Beer or Search. can someone tell me where i went wrong.
it says something like this:

> line 40, in call
> self.showdata()
> AttributeError: 'Search' object has no attribute 'showdata'

here is my code:

```
from tkinter import *
import tkinter.font as tkFont

class Search:
    def __init__(self, parent):
        #BEER FRAME
        self.beerframe = Frame(parent)
        self.beerframe.grid(row=0, column=0)
        
        self.beerheader = Frame(self.beerframe, bg="dodgerblue2", width=320, height=200)
        self.beerheader.grid_propagate(0)
        self.beerheader.grid(row=0, columnspan=2)
        #BEER FRAME

        #SEARCH FRAME
        self.searchframe = Frame(parent)
        self.searchframe.grid(row=0, column=0)
        
        self.searchheader = Frame(self.searchframe, bg="dodgerblue2", width=320, height=200)
        self.searchheader.grid_propagate(0)
        self.searchheader.grid(row=0, columnspan=2)
        
        self.searchentry = Entry(self.searchheader, width=30)
        self.searchentry.grid(row=0, column=0, padx=20, pady=20)

        self.searchbutton = Button(self.searchheader, text="Search", bg="deep sky blue", activebackground="deep sky blue", anchor=NE, command=self.call)
        self.searchbutton.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky=NE, padx=20, pady=20)

        self.errorlabel = Label(self.searchheader, text="Error: Invallad Word Entered")
        #SEARCH FRAME

    def call(self):
        self.frames = {
            "Beer": self.beerframe,
            "Search": self.searchframe,
        }
        search_string = self.searchentry.get()
        frame = self.frames.get(search_string, None)
        if frame:
            self.showdata()
        else:
            self.errorlabel.grid(row=1, columnspan=2)


root = Tk()
root.title("Search For File") 
root.geometry("320x200+200+200") 
interface = Search(root)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: where are the frames You want to find?

Comment: also don't use `from module import *` You should specify what You want to import

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Start by creating a dictionary with the keys being the strings you want the user to type, and the values being the frames.

```
self.frames = {
    "beer": self.BeerFrame,
    "search": self.searchframe,
}
```

Then, it's just a matter of looking up the frame when the user types something in:

```
search_string = self.searchentry.get()
frame = self.frames.get(search_string, None)
if frame:
    <show the frame>
else:
    <the user entered an invalid string
```

Comment: it kind of worked, edited the question coud you find a solution?

Comment: @Stormmv You haven't defined `showdata()`

Answer (score 0):

A bit late here but I made a simple example of what could the searching stuff look like (also improved the code to match PEP 8 at least to some extent), main benefit is that You don't have to enter full name for it to get searched, also it will output multiple options that matched the search term, it will also show if nothing was found or if nothing was entered:

```
from tkinter import Tk, Frame, Button, Entry, Label
import tkinter.font as tkFont
from functools import partial


class Search:
    def __init__(self, parent, search_items):
        # SEARCH FRAME
        self.parent = parent
        self.search_items = search_items
        
        self.search_frame = Frame(self.parent)
        self.search_frame.grid(row=0, column=0)

        self.search_header = Frame(self.search_frame, bg="dodgerblue2", width=320, height=60)
        self.search_header.grid_propagate(0)
        self.search_header.grid(row=0, columnspan=2)

        self.search_entry = Entry(self.search_header, width=30)
        self.search_entry.grid(row=0, column=0, padx=20, pady=20)

        self.search_button = Button(self.search_header, text="Search", bg="deep sky blue",
                                    activebackground="deep sky blue", anchor='ne',
                                    command=self.search)
        self.search_button.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky='ne', padx=20, pady=20)
        # SEARCH FRAME
        self.result_frame = Frame(self.parent)
        
        self.not_found_label = Label(self.result_frame, text='Not Found!')
        self.no_input = Label(self.result_frame, text='Enter a Search Term!')

        self.button_identities = []
    
    def search(self):
        self.button_identities = []

        for item in self.parent.winfo_children():
            if item in self.search_items:
                item.grid_forget()
        for item in self.result_frame.winfo_children():
            item.pack_forget()

        self.result_frame.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky='nsew')
        
        keyword = self.search_entry.get().lower()
        if keyword == '':
            self.no_input.pack()
            self.search_entry.delete(0, 'end')
            return

        for index, item in enumerate(self.search_items):
            if keyword in item.search_term:
                btn = Button(self.result_frame, text=item.search_term.capitalize(),
                             command=partial(self.place_, index))
                btn.pack(fill='x', expand=True)
                self.button_identities.append(btn)
            else:
                self.not_found()
    
    def not_found(self):
        self.not_found_label.pack()
        self.search_entry.delete(0, 'end')

    def place_(self, index):
        self.search_entry.delete(0, 'end')
        for item in self.result_frame.winfo_children():
            item.pack_forget()
        self.result_frame.grid_forget()
        self.search_items[index].grid()


class HomeFrame(Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.parent = parent
        self.search_term = 'home frame'

        self.label = Label(self, text='Home Frame')
        self.label.pack(fill='both')


class NotHomeFrame(Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.parent = parent
        self.search_term = 'not home frame'

        self.label = Label(self, text='Not Home Frame')
        self.label.pack(fill='both')


root = Tk()

list_of_frames = [HomeFrame(root), NotHomeFrame(root)]

root.title("Search For File")
# root.geometry("320x60+200+200")
interface = Search(root, list_of_frames)
root.mainloop()
```

classes `HomeFrame` and `NotHomeFrame` are for an example of how You would make those frames